# How can I submit a page on link click using Jquery without the presence of a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, submit, client-side

I want to fake a page submit (post) on clicking a link. I need to pass two parameters in the post , the id (var "x" in the code below, and submitted="true") to the page index.php. I need to fake a submit (full page load) and not just an ajax request.

```
<a href="#" id="5" class="rootcontent">Title</a>

$("a.rootcontent").live('click', function(){
    var x= $(this).attr("id"); 
   //need the code to submit the page to index.php with two $_POST variables (x and submitted=true)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to append a form to the document and submit it. Something like the following (not tested, but it should work):

```
var form = $('<form method="post" id="form-to-be-submitted" action="/index.php"><input type="hidden" name="x" value="' + x + '"/><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/></form>');
$(document.body).append(form);
form.submit();
```

Comment: I wouldn't give the form an ID; there is a possibility it will conflict with an existing ID. Instead, just store the form in a variable before adding it to the DOM, and submit using the variable; `$form = $("<form..."); $(document.body).append($form); $form.submit()`

Comment: @meagar I don't think there will be a case of ID collision, but it's still better form, I've updated my example (it was only meant as an example, it's still not tested).

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of the following:

- use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (ajax)
- add a form and handle the submit event to add x and submitted
- add a form with hidden fields for x and submitted